# Python: "exec open(external.py).read() in globals(), locals()" while allowing it to manipulate objects in main script

Tags: python, python-2.7, exec

### Background

I am using the dreaded `exec open` in Python 2.7, to execute two other Python files (`file1.py` and `file2.py`) from within my main script (`main_file.py`).

I'm a novice programmer, and I do this because the external files are located in other locations on the drive. Many different Python scripts beside `main_file.py` access the contents in both `file1.py` and `file2.py`. So when I update those two, all scripts accessing them will benefit from the update. They contain lists and generic rules that apply to all my Python scripts.

Everything worked fine until I introduced a new function `newFunction()` into `main_file.py`. `newFunction()` is called from inside another function of the main script called `topFunction()`.

---

### Error

> `exec open(file2.py).read()`
>
> SyntaxError: unqualified exec is not allowed in function `'topFunction()'` because it contains a nested function with free variables.

The error message actually points to Step 2 below:

1. `topFunction()` first calls `newFunction()`
2. `topFunction()` wants to `exec open(file2.py)`

To complicate things a bit further, `newFunction()`accesses list variables from **`file1.py`** that have previously been executed into `main_file.py`. And furthermore, `file2.py` also references those lists from `main_file.py` once they have been executed from `file1.py`.

---

### Attempt at solution

So, I found something which at least could get the script to run, without error message.

```
exec open(file2.py).read() in globals(), locals()
```

This *will actually* execute the code in `file2.py` and then continue to run what's left to run in `main_file.py`.
**But the problem is that `file2.py` will *not*** be able to manipulate variables (objects) that are native in `main_file.py`.

I can't get `file2.py` to set `myString = "pancakes"` and then get `main_file.py` to `print myString`.

This was possible before introducing `newFunction()`, when I simply used `exec open(file2.py).read()`.

---

### Question

Is there a work-around to get something like this working, in a way so that an externally executed script can also affect variables that are used in the main script?

```
exec open(file2.py).read() in globals(), locals()
```

Comment: Why for the love of the internet don't you just do `import file2`?

Comment: @Torxed `from file2 import *` gives the same problem, *unqualified exec is not allowed in function … because it contains a nested function with free variables*

Comment: `from import file2 *` is not valid, `from file2 import *` however is. What's the content of `file2` that makes it so you can't import it? It makes no sense.

Comment: @Torxed I really don't know, if it's not that `file2` references variables in `main_file` that were originally exec'ed from `file1`, I don't know.

Comment: If you create a new `main_file.py` that only contains `import file2`, I guarantee it this will work.

Answer (score 2):

Quoting from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#execfile):

> This function is similar to the exec statement, but parses a file
>   instead of a string. It is different from the import statement in that
>   it does not use the module administration — it reads the file
>   unconditionally and does not create a new module. [1]
>
> The arguments are a file name and two optional dictionaries. The file
>   is parsed and evaluated as a sequence of Python statements (similarly
>   to a module) using the globals and locals dictionaries as global and
>   local namespace. If provided, locals can be any mapping object.
>   Remember that at module level, globals and locals are the same
>   dictionary. If two separate objects are passed as globals and locals,
>   the code will be executed as if it were embedded in a class
>   definition.

As so you should try this:

```
execfile('file1.py')
execfile('file2.py')
```

Comment: I just tested your solution and the variable manipulations are not propagated from `file2.py` to the main file. This is why I originally went for `exec open` instead of `execfile`.

Comment: @Winterflags: Works fine here.